# How to help my cat in this situation?

Tags: cats, psychology, fear

We have three bedrooms. Me and my mom share one bedroom and for various reasons Bhutu(my cat) is allowed only in our bedroom, and not the other two, during night time when we all sleep.

Now I often have nightmares and shout in dream. My mom says that at that time Bhutu gets terribly afraid and runs for cover under my mom's belly.

So how to take care of my cat and ensure that she doesn't get afraid anymore?

**NOTE:**

We have only three bedrooms. The occupants of the other two bedrooms won't allow the cat in night. And if kept alone in the living room, the cat will keep crying all night. The cat can't stay alone, it is in her mentality. And she is a NEVER been outdoor cat, other than being taken out for a walk on a leash. And given the hazardous wild life here, she won't survive outdoor.

So the only solution is somehow make the atmosphere in my room more comfortable for the cat.

Like if provided with something before she goes to sleep, or making her sleep in a particular place so that she may be less startled by sudden loud noise. Or if there is some helpful scent available to soothe the cat.

Or may be I should make a particular change in behavior when I am awake to give the cat more assurance. And so on.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't agree with the assessment that this question is off topic. I'm sorry that you suffer from nightmares, but unfortunately we are not the right people who can help you. That's what professional psychologists are for. Please rephrase the question and concentrate on the cat's behavior rather than your nightmares. Clarify what your desired goal or specific question is ("So what is the way out of this situation?" is too broad) and the question can be reopened.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you trying to keep the cat from being afraid? Is it disruptive to your mother (who, I assume would already be disrupted by your yells)? 
Cats are easily startled when they are sleeping, so your cat's reaction is not unusual. I sneeze and my cats will often jump off the bed in temporary fright.  
There's not a way to prevent your cat from being afraid and hiding in these situations, except for what Donkey answered below. Remove the cat from the bedroom, or seek help for your nightmares to prevent them.

Comment: @Elmy This still looks like a people issue to me.  There are currently two re-open votes and I see you think the question has potential.  If it gets the required re-open votes with out my interference that is fine. If you "Elmy" believe the question has been successfully edited sufficiently let me know I and I will re-open it at your request

Comment: @Sonevol Would it be ok to leave the door open so the cat could leave the room, but not the house? Then she could walk away from a fearfull situation and comr back when she caed down.

Comment: @Elmy Sorry for the late reply. I have shifted to one of the other bedrooms, with current bedroom only for mom and the cat. It was the only option

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but it sounds a little bit strange ;)
As I understood, you have some mystic relation with your cat?
So, I see only two variants here:
1. You sleep with your cat in another bedroom;
2. Or you improve the quality of your sleep. Nightmares can be because of stress, you freeze during the night and many other reasons. Try special hormone for sleep - melatonin. It should help to sleep you better. And your cat won't be feared.